# PHP Contact form webpage

Tags: php, html, forms, validation, session

I have a big problem about a contact formular.
I have for a long time tried to get the form up and running whit php.
I have a captcha function also that I thing is working now whit checking.

But I need help whit form and php part:
 1. check all form field and give a error message when the input fields are not OK (right side off the input field in red color).
 2. Sendt out email if all is ok after check form fields. And give at message that the email have been sendt.

contactform.php

```
<?php session_start();
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
    if (empty($_POST["first_name"])) {
        $nameError = "Name is required";
    }
    else {
        $name = test_input($_POST["first_name"]);    
        // check name only contains letters and whitespace
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
            $nameError = "Only letters and white space allowed";
        }
    }

    // code for check server side validation
    if(empty($_SESSION['6_letters_code'] ) || strcasecmp($_SESSION['6_letters_code'], $_POST['6_letters_code']) != 0){  
        $msg="<span style='color:red'>The Validation code does not match!</span>";// Captcha verification is incorrect.     
    }else{// Captcha verification is Correct. Final Code Execute here!      
        $msg="<span style='color:green'>The Validation code has been matched.</span>";      
    }
}   
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="generator" content="CoffeeCup HTML Editor (www.coffeecup.com)">
  <meta name="dcterms.created" content="sø, 22 maj 2016 18:08:14 GMT">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="keywords" content="">
  <title></title>    
</head>

<body>    
    <form action="" method="post" name="contactform" id="contactform" <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">     
        <table width="550px">     
            <tr>
        <td valign="top">     
                <label for="first_name">First Name *</label>
            </td>     
                <td valign="top">
                <input  type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
                <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameError;?></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>     
                <td valign="top"">     
                <label for="last_name">Last Name *</label>     
                </td>     
                <td valign="top">     
                <input  type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
            </td>
            </tr>     
            <tr>     
                <td valign="top">     
                <label for="email">Email Address *</label>     
                </td>     
                <td valign="top">     
                <input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30">     
                </td>     
            </tr>     
            <tr>     
                <td valign="top">     
                <label for="telephone">Telephone Number</label>     
                </td>     
                <td valign="top">     
                <input  type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="30" size="30">     
                </td>     
            </tr>     
            <tr>     
                <td valign="top">     
                <label for="comments">Comments *</label>     
                </td>     
                <td valign="top">     
                <textarea  name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6"></textarea>     
                </td>     
            </tr>     
            <tr>     
                <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
                <?php if(isset($msg)){?>
                <?php echo $msg;?><?php } ?><br>
                    <img src="captcha_code_file.php?rand=<?php echo rand(); ?>" id='captchaimg' ><br>
                    <label for='message'>Enter the code above here :</label><br>
                    <input id="6_letters_code" name="6_letters_code" type="text"><br>
                    <small>Can't read the image? click <a href='javascript: refreshCaptcha();'>here</a> to refresh</small>
                    </p>    
                <input name="Submit" type="submit" onclick="return validate();" value="Submit" class="button1">     
                </td>     
            </tr>     
        </table>     
    </form>

  <script language='JavaScript' type='text/javascript'>
    function refreshCaptcha() {
        var img = document.images['captchaimg'];
        img.src = img.src.substring(0,img.src.lastIndexOf("?"))+"?rand="+Math.random()*1000;
    }
  </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Send_form_email.php
This code is working if I use it:

But then the user is forced away from the form.
And all the error messages is given on a blank php page and not in the form whit the captcha also.

```
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {     
  // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
  $email_to = "my email address";
  $email_subject = "this is a message";     
  function died($error) {
    // your error code can go here
    echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
    echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
    echo $error."<br /><br />";
    echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
    die();
  }
    // validation expected data exists

  if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
      !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
      !isset($_POST['email']) ||
      !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
      !isset($_POST['comments']))
  {
    died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');
  } 

  $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
  $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
  $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
  $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
  $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required         

  $error_message = "";

  $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {     
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) { 
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

  if(strlen($comments) < 2) { 
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) { 
    died($error_message);
  }
  $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";         

  function clean_string($string) {
    $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
    return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
  }

  $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
  $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
  $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
  $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
  $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";

    // create email headers     
    $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
    'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

?>     
<!-- include your own success html here -->     
Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.
<?php } ?>
```

Send_email_form.php

Comment: Have you think of using jQuery validation? https://jqueryvalidation.org/

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you're using this if statement.

```
if(strlen($error_message) > 0) { 
   died($error_message);
}
```

If you want to show the error message on the actual contact form. You need to use

// Change in Send_email_form.php

```
 if(strlen($error_message) > 0) 
 { 
    header('Location: contactform.php?err='.$error_message);
    exit;
 }
```

// Change in contactform.php - Use this piece of code where you want to display the errors on page.

```
if(isset($_GET['err']) && !empty( $_GET['err'] )
{
    echo $_GET['err'];
}
```

Comment: I have tried to change things after your help, but still I am in big problems still.

I have now removed 3 files to 2 files now:

contactform.php whit the form
captcha_code_file.php capcha and php.

What I am going for is a message under the input fields.

input first_name (You have not enter your name)
input last_name (You have not enter your lastname)
input email (You have not enter your email)
input telephone (optional dont have to be field out)
input comments (You have not enter your comments)
captcha_code check.

Comment: Maybe I can send a email to you if that i more easy?

Comment: Sure you can email me. I'll fix and then resend you the files again. my email is usman.nxb@gmail.com

Comment: Super I will send it now

Comment: I've resent the contactform.php file to you.

Comment: Thanks I have sendt a reply email to you.